# How do I enable SSL on my server?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ssl

When changing my settings to environment variables I started getting the error "server does not support SSL, but SSL was required." I thought I had done this, and if not I'm not sure what I still have to do. I've 'djangosecure' and 'sslserver' in installed apps. ssslmode is 'on' in my postgres.conf:

```
#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
ssl = on                # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
                    # (change requires restart)
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on     # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'      # (change requires restart)
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'        # (change requires restart)
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'     # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ca_file = ''           # (change requires restart)
#ssl_crl_file = ''          # (change requires restart)
#password_encryption = on
#db_user_namespace = off
#row_security = on
```

The interesting thing to me is that throughout the entire time of development I didn't get this error; only now that I've tried to change my settings to environment variables for production. What is the setting or configuration that I'm missing?

I have this in my databases configuration:
    'OPTIONS': {
            'sslmode': 'require',
    },

Might this may have something to do with my original installation of Postgres? I installed Postgres outside of my virtualenv and so have had to access the db command line with: locate psql | grep bin, and then copy the path, instead of simply writing psql. Up until now this hasn't given me problems except for the inconvenience, but could this be part of the problem?

python3 manage.py dbshell

CommandError: You appear not to have the 'psql' program installed or on your path.

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
```

django.db.utils.OperationalError: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required

Comment: SSL needs to also be enabled on your webserver, here's how to configure it on nginx http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: @Eugene Do you know why is this all of the sudden necessary for the app to run on my local server just for development? I wasn't having this problem before...

Comment: First things first to troubleshoot: try connecting to your PostgreSQL with a simple `psql` client, using `"sslmode=require"` in order to check that the TLS handshake is successful. Only when that works try to make it work from Django.

Comment: Patrick, I thought I needed to try another way of asking since I wasn't making progress with the last version. And the handshake is unsuccessful: psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 0):

There is a comment sign in front of `ssl = on` in your file, so the default value `ssl = off` is used.

To enable SSL, you need a certificate and a key as well, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html).

Comment: Ah ok, something so simple I overlook... Working on this now. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Laurenz I uncommented the conf file and have a certificate and key in the database directory but it's still giving the same error.

Comment: @Whodini you shouldn't have edited our question as now this answer makes no sense anymore because it related to the previous version of your question...

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: is now asking:  Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: DATABASE_URL=postgresql://urser:password@localhost:5432/database

Comment: Now getting this error: psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: tlsv1 alert internal error

Comment: Did you look into the log?